# How to parse HTML with a Snowflake UDF

Tags: javascript, java, html, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, user-defined-functions

Snowflake supports JavaScript UDFs, but the DOM Parser doesn't work (for security reasons).

For example, I get these errors with a JS UDF:

```
JavaScript execution error: Uncaught ReferenceError: document is not defined

JavaScript execution error: Uncaught ReferenceError: DOMParser is not defined

etc
```

How can I parse HTML documents with Snowflake then?

Answer (score 4):

You can use a Java UDF and jsoup to parse HTML in SQL.

First `PUT` the [jsoup.jar](https://jsoup.org/download) in place with SnowSQL:

`put 'file:///Users/fhoffa/Downloads/jsoup-1.13.1.jar' @~;`

Then you can create a Java UDF for it.

For example, to extract text out of HTML:

```java
create or replace function jsoup_text(x string)
returns string
language java
imports = ('@~/jsoup-1.13.1.jar')
handler='MyClass.text'
as
$$
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;

class MyClass {
    public static String text(String x) {
        return Jsoup.parse(x).text();
    }
}
$$;
```

Which can be called like this:

```sql
select jsoup_text('This is a <strong>strong</strong> number <date>2013</date>');
```

Which returns the text without any HTML extra elements.

Or to extract all links URLs from a document:

```java
create or replace function jsoup_all_links(x string)
returns array
language java
imports = ('@~/jsoup-1.13.1.jar')
handler='MyClass.extractLinks'
as
$$
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;

class MyClass {
    public static String[] extractLinks(String x) {
        return Jsoup.parse(x)
            .select("a[href]")
            .stream().map(s -> s.attr("abs:href"))
            .toArray(String[]::new);
    }
}
$$;
```

And it's ready to work:

```sql
select jsoup_all_links('The best <a href="http://snowflake.com">Snowflake</a> <a href="https://reddit.com/r/snowflake">subreddit</a>');
```

Which returns the array `["http://snowflake.com", "https://reddit.com/r/snowflake"]`.

Read more:

- https://medium.com/snowflake/new-in-snowflake-java-udfs-with-a-kotlin-nlp-example-e52d94d33468